# Error when using MailKit's ImapClient in a thread

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm using MailKit library to save attachments from newly arrived emails every x amount of seconds. I need to run this process on a separate thread so it doesn't block my UI.
Whenever my code gets to ImapClient instantiation, it throws an error: **"Thread was being aborted."**

ExceptionState: **"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack."**

Stack Trace:

```
at MailKit.MailService..ctor(IProtocolLogger protocolLogger)

at MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient..ctor(IProtocolLogger protocolLogger)

at MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient..ctor()

at Domain.ApInvoicePrinting.<>c.<Run>b__4_0() in C:\...\MyClass.cs:line 29
```

[image]

Code:

```
var task = new Task(() => 
{
   try
   {
       using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient()) // Exception thrown at this line
       {
          ...
       }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       ...
    } 
}

task.Start();
```

I've tried running it using System.Threading.Timer and still getting same error. However, on the main thread everything works fine.
What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the StackTrace of this exception? Can't help you until you provide at least that much.

Comment: @jstedfast Just added stack trace.

Comment: That StackTrace doesn't make any sense at all. The .ctor has literally nothing outside of field initialization. The only explanation is that the thread has been aborted by elsewhere in your program.

Comment: Here's the code in case you were wondering: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/MailKit/MailService.cs#L74

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was running that code within unit test project with MS Test. When I ran the exact same code using Console App everything worked fine! Though, I'm not sure what is the reasoning behind that.